# Formatting in cell depending on row in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Lets say I have a **name in cell A1**. I'd like to make that cell green if there is **"o" or "x"** in any of the cells spanning **B1:Z1.**

Also, could you do this thing on a larger scale if you have 20 names under column A from A1:A20; so you don't need to format each cell individually?

Here is an example of my naughty and nice list:

```
    A          B       C       D
    Name      Mon     Tue     Wed
    Mark       x               x
    Donna      o       x       o
    Amy                x
```

I tried to do it with conditional formatting on A2

> **=OR($B$2:$H$2="x";$B$2:$H$2="o")**

but in this instance it only works on the first two examples, since the B column has a value in it.
Is it possible to do that on a list of 40 people on a mass scale. to not have to do formatting for each row seperately?

I'm using Excel 2013 if that helps in any way.

Comment: It should be able to be done with conditional formating. If any cells in `B1:Z1` reference `A1` you may have a circular reference problem. I can't be bothered testing it until you show what you have **actually tried** and **why/where it doesn't work**. That's how SO works - show an attempt to solve the problem and we'll probably be able to help you. Show us nothing then **expect nothing beck.**

Comment: added a bit more information into my original post. I hope it makes it clearer. Was trying to find a span or array refference in formulas but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do what you have (the OR expression,
    =OR(NOT(ISBLANK(Table2[@[B]:[D]])))  (as an array, shift-+ctrl+enter)
) and put it in it's own column(E).  Then just look at that with a formula in the conditional formatting that looks like:
    =E2

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, now that I understand the question, the conditional format option can be applied.

Select cells `A2:A20`
Go to Conditional Formatting on the Home tab
Click on `New Rule...` and you will see something like this

[image]

Click the "Use a formula" option and enter this in the "Format values where..."

```
=OR(COUNTIF(A2:H2,"x")>0,COUNTIF(A2:H2,"o")>0)
```

and then click the Format... button to apply a green fill to the cells.

I'm using `COUNTIF`s because comparing or testing a range for a specific value needs an array formula which I've never really considered for a conditional format. It may work but I prefer the KISS principle.

Answer (score 0):

for me this formula: `=OR(B2:X2="o",B2:X2="x")` produces the desired result, and I don't experience the strage problem "when B is empty" as you describe.

Not sure about the difference between `;` and `,` separators - it has something to do with regional settings (some info [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/issue-array-constants-may-unexpectedly-contain-backslash-characters-HA010222558.aspx))